# How to access a listView from a different user control?

Tags: c#, windows

I want to access a listView from a different control to input data from a structure but I have no idea how.`Savethescore ScoreDialog = new Savethescore();
        HallofGlory HofG = new HallofGlory();

```
    private void saveTheScoreToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ScoreDialog.ShowDialog();

        if (ScoreDialog.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string sLevel = "Level 1";

            if (bLevel1)
                sLevel = "Level 1";
            if (bLevel2)
                sLevel = "Level 2";
            SStat Player = new SStat(ScoreDialog.textBox1.Text, sLevel, m_iHits, m_iShots, m_iSpeed, m_iSpeed, CountPercents(m_iHits, m_iShots));


            ListViewItem NewPlayer = new ListViewItem(Player.m_sName);
            NewPlayer.SubItems.Add(Player.m_sLevel);
            NewPlayer.SubItems.Add(Player.m_iHits.ToString());
            NewPlayer.SubItems.Add(Player.m_iShots.ToString());
            NewPlayer.SubItems.Add(Player.m_iSpeed.ToString());
            NewPlayer.SubItems.Add(Player.m_dPercentage.ToString() + "%");
            HofG.listView1.Items.Add(NewPlayer);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Can You please share the code ?

Comment: Searching for [\[C#\] How to access  from a different form?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5BC%23%5D+How+to+access++from+a+different+form%3F) on SO yields 528 results.